# Multi tasking barring app

Tags: linux, window

I want to make a window/unix/linux app which don't allow access to other apps unless it is closed. In short, the app don't allow multitasking.
If possible, please tell me the language in which I can code and all the other useful info.

Comment: I am sure on Linux it is impossible to do that, in fact you can't prevent OTHER users to open what they want.